# Beside of number of purchases I need to show value left for another purchase

Tags: oracle

I need to show number of purchases, left amount for another purchase. What is function I can add to my code below(it is marked as comment section:

```
    DECLARE
       lv_prchd_num NUMBER(4,2):= 0;
       lv_iprice_num NUMBER(5,2) := 23.23;
       lv_t2spend_num NUMBER(5,2);
       lv_left_num NUMBER(6,2);
   BEGIN
       lv_t2spend_num := '&lv_t2spend';
       WHILE (lv_prchd_num * lv_iprice_num) <= lv_t2spend_num LOOP
              lv_prchd_num := lv_prchd_num + 1;
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This time I have   
              purchased: '||lv_prchd_num||'st/th item');
              /*
              lv_left_num := lv_t2spend_num - lv_iprice_num;
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('It is left over: '||lv_left_num);
              ;*/
      END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number of items purchased are: '||lv_prchd_num);
   END;
```

Comment: I think it should be `lv_left_num := lv_t2spend_num - lv_prchd_num * lv_iprice_num` . Having said that, we expect you to post few more details of how exactly you need the output to be and some sample data.

Comment: It worked, thank you @KaushikNayak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use :

```
lv_left_num := lv_t2spend_num - lv_prchd_num * lv_iprice_num;
```

i.e subtracting the running value of purchases from total amount to spend.